# Does Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData support API versioning?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

I've been searching around and havn't been able to find any samples or discussion around Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData and API versioning. Does anyone know if this is supported?

Comment: [Reference for Versioning](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Versioning-via-the-URL-Path)

Comment: [Swagger OData](https://github.com/rbeauchamp/Swashbuckle.OData)

Comment: Unfortunately those examples show versioning for ASP.NET Web API and OData v4.0 but not for ASP.NET Core. I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.

Comment: Looks like there is currently no support for versioning based on this thread https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/109

Answer (score 0):

Versioning AsoNetCore Odata is now possible: https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/New-Services-Quick-Start#aspnet-core-with-odata-v40

Integration with Swashbuckle/Swagger however is not yet fully supported